# How can I write an installer for terminal server

Tags: windows-installer, terminal-services

I am writing an installer( msi file) which needs to be run on a terminal server
It must be multi use in other words all logged in users should be able to run that program

when the installer is run it writes a set of registry entries to HKLM
it also drops an activate.exe in the prog files directory

Each user needs to run activate.exe so that apart from activation logic the correct HKCU entries get created

I guess my question is 
Does my installer have to "special" or diff in any way for the terminal services installation or does the admin on the machine have to do something to install it "correctly"

How can I make sure that a startmenu entry that points to the activate exe shows up for every user
is there like some sort of shared mode install

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not it installs "correctly" is entirely up to the nature of your program and its install/activate methods. As an example, Office 2003 and Office 2007 VSTO add-ins have two different mechanisms (and registry paths) for "all user" installs -- 2007 is more proactive, deals with trust better, etc. etc. Depending on what your program does or looks for, you may or may not need to tweak your install, but most likely, installing to HKLM should be fine for any users who have logon rights to the machine.

Comment: i guess my only query then is how do i ensure that a start menu shortcut is installed for all users 
is that something that just happens automatically?

Comment: Just use the appropriate All Users' Start Menu folder depending on the OS:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial44.html

Or do you want to trigger an action or behavior for all users? I'm a little confused.